# Jquery выводит undefinded

Tags: jquery

Код

```
<script>
        function src()
        {
        var $img = $(this).find('img');
        alert($img.attr('src'));
        }
</script>
```

Верстка

```
  <div class="miniwork" onclick="src()">
                <img src="./img/miniwork.jpg" >
                </div>
```

Comment: Может из-за того, что имя переменной начинается со знака доллара?

Answer (score 2):

1. Вариант на чистом JS http://jsfiddle.net/dgM9r/1/
2. Вариант на jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/dgM9r/2/

[[@Zepp](/users/14896/zepp)](/users/14896/zepp), имена переменных в жабаскрипте могут начинаться со знака доллара

Answer (score 2):

А вы попробуйте вывести alert(this). this в вашем контексте - window, естественно у него нет никакого src.

Чтоб данный код заработал, надо передать в функцию объект.

```
<div class="miniwork" onclick="src(this)">
    <img src="./img/miniwork.jpg"/>
</div>
```

и тогда

```
function src(div) {
    var $img = $(div).find('img');
    alert($img.attr('src'));
}
```

Но лучше вообще так не делать. Назначать обработчики логичнее и правильнее непосредственно в скрипте:

```
$(".miniwork").click(function(){
  var $img = $(this).find('img');
  alert($img.attr('src'));
});
```

и из разметки вовсе убрать onclick=...